# Why does this solid state relay circuit work sometimes and not other times? (stuck closed)

Tags: solid-state-relay, open-collector

It's  a very simple open collector output from one device driving a solid-state relay (VO1400) in another device. You can see the power transistors (BS868) that drive OUTn.n in the circuit diagram. Two of these are connected to the OUT1/2 K signals inputs on the other device.

When the transistor is turned on the OUTn.n and therefore OUT1/2 K signals are hard pulled to GND - the relay closes nicely. When the transistor is off the OUTn.n is floating (high impedance) as is the OUT1/2 K signals as there is no pull-up on the circuit - sometimes the circuit works and sometimes it doesn't - stuck closed or closes/opens quickly in succession.

The feeling from the designer is that this should work OK, whereas we have proved that it doesn't. One side of the LED (anode) in the solid-state relay is connected to 6V through a resistor that sets the forward current to approx 5mA.

What we see is the that cathode of the LED floats to a value - if the value is up around approx 4.8V then the circuit works and the relay opens. When the value is less (~3.8V) the relay remains in the closed state - circuit operation failure.

I can see from the relay datasheet what the forward current switch on/off values are, and I can see that there is a voltage difference across the LED, but what I can't explain is how we are getting current as there is no path to GND - is it leakage through the transistor or something? Can someone explain this behaviour to me please?

The GNDs of both devices are connected to the same supply (both driven from the same 6V as well.)

It seems clear that the circuit needs a pull-up resistor to guarantee a clean switch off but I'd like to be able to explain why.

It also seems like the pull-up resistor needs to match the values of R3/R4 on the anode of the LED - again not sure why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without a whole lot of thought as to whether this would actually fix it: have you tried adding a base-emitter resistor to the BC868s?

Comment: Also, the VO1400 only requires at most 3.2 mA to turn on; why are you using a transistor rated to 2 A?

Comment: Hi @Hearth - they are definitely mismatched, but the system is using 2 pre-designed devices. The open collector outputs are in one device and the relays in a different device, both connected together. In theory should still work OK, but certainly overkill. I believe the base is always being driven by U4 shift register so base/emitter resistor not required??

Comment: A very long shot, are the 868's connected the right way round? I'm thinking, how could they leak so much? Have you confirmed the leakage of those directly? Use a DMM on mA with a 1k resistor in series to limit the current, connected from OUTn to 6 V. What is U4 driving their base voltages to?